# How to show the web-service data in tab fragments using single fragment java file

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity

I am using tab-layout and viewpager.I formed 6 tab with one fragment java file.but i am not able you show the data perfectlty. please help i have been struggling since last two weeks

Comment: post the code...how can someone help you without seeing what you have done so far?

Comment: Share some of your code. Your question is not clear. Describe your problem briefly.